# Issue assigning custom UIColor to class property

Tags: objective-c, methods, uicolor, cgcolor

I'm having troubles passing through a custom UIColor to a method I've created.

Basically, I have a class that extends the UIButton class, in which I can assign whatever colours I want to different, commonly modified, properties of the class. To do this I often have to set the colours of things to "uiColorParameter.CGColor", or "uiColorParameter". My issue is that when I pass a custom colour as an argument (So instead of [UIColor whiteColor] (for example) I do [UIColor colorWithRed:...], the app crashes with the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)".

2 times the class is utilised in a view controller.

```
[_beginButton updateButtonBorderWithCornerRadius:10 borderWidth:2.75 borderColor:[RoundedButton appRedColor]];
[_beginButton setEventEffectsWithColor:[UIColor redColor] secondColor:[RoundedButton appRedColor]];
```

In the custom classes H

```
@property (assign) UIColor *pColor;
@property (assign) UIColor *sColor;
```

In the custom class

```
- (void)updateButtonBorderWithCornerRadius:(CGFloat)bRadius borderWidth:(CGFloat)bWidth borderColor:(UIColor *)bColor
{
    self.layer.cornerRadius = bRadius;
    self.layer.borderWidth = bWidth;
    self.layer.borderColor = bColor.CGColor;
}

- (void)setEventEffectsWithColor:(UIColor *)fColor secondColor:(UIColor *)sColor
{
    [self setPrimaryBorderColor:fColor];
    [self setSecondaryBorderColor:sColor];

    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(highlight) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(unhighlight) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(unhighlight) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
}

- (void)highlight
{
    self.layer.borderColor = pColor.CGColor;
    self.titleLabel.textColor = pColor;
}

- (void)unhighlight
{
    self.layer.borderColor = sColor.CGColor; //Where the error occurs
    self.titleLabel.textColor = sColor;
}

- (void)setPrimaryBorderColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    pColor = color;
}

- (void)setSecondaryBorderColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    sColor = color;
}

+ (UIColor *)appRedColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.68 green:0.14 blue:0.09 alpha:1];
}
```

The first method "updateButtonBorder..." works completely fine, no errors. However, for the second method, regardless of how you pass through the custom UIColor (whether has a class variable, as I've done, or as a literal [UIColor colorWithRed:...) it will crash. However, if I send an ordinary [UIColor whiteColor], for example, it will work perfectly fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a memory management problem due to your `pColor` and `sColor` properties being declared as `assign` instead of `strong`.

It appears to work with system colors because those system color instances are probably kept in memory by UIKit. But your custom colors are not.

Change:

```
@property (assign) UIColor *pColor;
@property (assign) UIColor *sColor;
```

to:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *pColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *sColor;
```

You should very rarely, if ever, use `assign` with object pointers.

Comment: Cheers for all the help. After your initial comment, I realised you would likely suggest I have the wrong var attributes assigned, so I refreshed myself on what each of the attributes do and resolved the issue by assigning the attributes (the same as suggested by you).